# How can I filter that text in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this String

```
[id:300][OK:null], [id:303][ENVIROMENT:null], [id:3027][USER:null], [id:98][SISTEMA:null]
```

I want to delete from [id: to the next] so that it stays that way:

```
[OK:null], [ENVIROMENT:null], [USER:null], [SISTEMA:null]
```

Comment: Ideally you'd want to use a regex replacement here.  But MySQL does not support this out of the box.  This is a hard problem to handle in MySQL.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: Im using Oracle

Comment: I'd be tempted to tag the question with the RDBMS you're using rather than the RDBMS you're not using

Comment: Replace the question tag from "mysql"  to "oracle" as you are using oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using Oracle, then simply you can use the REGEX_REPLACE as below:

```
select str, REGEXP_REPLACE(str,'\[(id.*?)\]') from x;
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/32953/7)